# find the length of any arc on a circle

Tags: c, algorithm, geometry

I have an interesting (to me anyway) problem.  I am working on OpenServo.org for V4 and I am trying to determine the length of an arc of travel and its direction.

I have a magnetic encoder that returns the position of the shaft from 0 to 4095.

The servo has two logical end points, call them MAX and MIN which are set in software and can be changed at any time, and the shaft must rotate (i.e. travel) on one arc between the MAX and MIN positions. For example in the picture the blue arc is valid but the red is not for all travel between and including MIN and MAX.

I am trying to work out a simple algorithm using only integer math that can tell me the distance between any two points A and B that can be anywhere on the circumference, bounded by MIN and MAX and with either A as the current place and B is the target position, or B is the current place and A is the target (which is denoted by a negative distance from B to A).  Note the side I allowed to travel is known, it is either "red" or "blue".

The issue is when the 4095/0 exists in the ARC, then the calculations get a bit interesting.

[image]

Comment: How do we know which side of the arc is valid? I.e. why is it the blue one, rather than the red one?

Comment: It is set in software to prevent the shaft from turning where it should not. For example this might be an elbow joint and the blue arc is valid but the red is mechanically not possible (or it could be that the red arc is allowed and A is 3000 and B is 2500, A and B indicate which ARC is valid for travel)..

Comment: Is there a guarantee that A and B won't be on opposite sides when you change MIN and MAX?

Comment: When MIN and MAX are changed, A and B are also changed to indicate which side you can travel so at all times A and B are on the correct arc between MIN and MAX

Comment: Thank you for the replies, two of the replies algorithms work and the third I could not get to work.  I really liked Mark Ransom's very simple logic, but I appreciated Paul Griffith's program.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I have asked a supplementary question about how to test that A and B are on the arc of travel => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149498/find-the-length-of-any-arc-on-a-circle-confrim-limits-are-on-the-required-arc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int rotate_diff(int a, int b, bool * clockwise);

int main(void) {
    int degrees_rotated, a, b;
    bool clockwise;

    a = 4040;
    b = 1060;
    degrees_rotated = rotate_diff(a, b, &clockwise);
    printf("A = %d, B = %d, rotation = %d degrees, direction = %s\n",
            a, b, degrees_rotated,
            (clockwise ? "clockwise" : "counter-clockwise"));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int rotate_diff(int a, int b, bool * clockwise) {
    static const int min = 2000;

    if ( a <= min ) {
        a += 4096;
    }
    if ( b <= min ) {
        b += 4096;
    }

    int degrees_rotated = b - a;
    if ( degrees_rotated > 0 ) {
        *clockwise = false;
    } else {
        degrees_rotated = -degrees_rotated;
        *clockwise = true;
    }

    return degrees_rotated * 360 / 4096;
}
```

Note that this gives you the degrees traveled, but not the distance traveled, since you don't tell us what dimensions of the shaft are. To get the distance traveled, obviously multiply the circumference by the degrees traveled divided by 360. If your points 0 through 4095 are some kind of known units, then just skip the conversion to degrees in the above algorithm, and change the variable names accordingly.

Comment: Comprehensive solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust all your coordinates so they're on the same side of your limit points. Since it's a circular system you can add 4096 without affecting the absolute position.

```
lowest = min(MIN, MAX);
if (A < lowest)
    A += 4096;
if (B < lowest)
    B += 4096;
distance = B - A;  /* or abs(B - A) */
```

In your example A would not be adjusted but B would be adjusted to 5156. The difference would be a positive 1116.

In your second example with A=3000 and B=2500, they're both above 2000 so neither would need adjustment. The difference is -500.

Comment: Very nice algorithm, clean and simple!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed something, this should give the result you need:

```
if MIN < A,B < MAX
    distance = A - B
else
   if A > MAX and B < MIN
       distance = A - (B + 4096)
   else if B > MAX and A < MIN
       distance = (A + 4096) - B
   else
       distance = A - B
```

(get the absolute value of the distance if you don't need the direction)

Comment: To work through your pseudo code, if 2000 < 4040, 1000 < 4000 distance = 4040 - 1060 which gives 2980 instead of 55 + 1060 = 1115 (I assume the ',' is an OR statement)?

Comment: Bah, should've used some normal syntax. I meant both A and B within (MIN, MAX) range.