# find the length of any arc on a circle - confrim limits are on the required arc

Tags: c, algorithm, geometry

This question follows on from [find the length of any arc on a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129025/find-the-length-of-any-arc-on-a-circle)

From that question:

I have a magnetic encoder that returns the position of the shaft from 0 to 4095.

The servo has two logical end points, call them MAX and MIN which are set in software and can be changed at any time, and the shaft must rotate (i.e. travel) on one arc between the MAX and MIN positions. For example in the picture the blue arc is valid but the red is not for all travel between and including MIN and MAX.

I am trying to work out a simple algorithm to validate that where travel is allowed on the BLUE side of my circle, that A and B are on the BLUE arc and neither are on the RED arc, and the opposite where if the allowed arc of travel is RED, then A and B are both on the RED arc?

[image: Top view of the servo shaft]

Note: A and B are set by the calling program and are always changing.

Comment: When you ask a new question, even if it is a follow-up of a previous question, the question itself should be self-contained.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I am writing actual code on the servo to test :-)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to my answer on your other question:

```
if (MIN > MAX)
    // swap MIN and MAX
if (A < MIN)
    A += 4096;
if (B < MIN)
    B += 4096;
if (min(A, B) < MAX && max(A, B) > MAX)
    // error!
```

First you force both points to be on the same side of MIN, then you test to see if they're on opposite sides of MAX.

Comment: Interesting, I have tested this for the BLUE arc and it works well, but unless I am missing something, how does it work if the RED arc is the side for allowable travel?

Comment: @user2836967 on the red arc both A and B will be less than highest.

Comment: @user2836967 I've changed the answer slightly, hopefully it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to restate the problem this way: Given the positions MIN, MAX and SHAFT, determine if both A and B are on the same arc that contains SHAFT.

The following code will determine if point `x` lies on the same arc defined by MIN, MAX and SHAFT. The assertions spell out the preconditions.

```
    assert(shaft != min);
    assert(shaft != max);
    assert(min < max);

    if (min < shaft && shaft < max) {
        return min < x && x < max;
    }

    return x < min || x > max;
```

Comment: If I understand your logic, all I need is any predefined point on the ARC of travel between min and max (shaft) and the above tests if x is on the same arc?

Comment: The above logic tests if `x` lies on the same arc that `shaft` lies on. An arc requires three points anyway, and it seemed the arc of interest was the one that involved shaft.